# Select Box API changed

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm reading a book called **Learning LIBGDX Game development** and I am having a problem with it, because a lot has changed since it was published. The issue is that the `Select Box` api has changed and doesn't allow me to do what it says in the book.

How can I make achieve the same behavior in select box as described in my book?

The error is on the line:

```
 selCharSkin = new SelectBox(CharacterSkin.values(), skinLibgdx);
```

it says: **The constructor SelectBox(CharacterSkin[], Skin) is undefined**

Quick fix: **Remove argument to match SelectBox(Skin)**

```
MenuScree.java
package com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.screens;

import javax.swing.plaf.ComboBoxUI;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.LabelStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Stack;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.game.Assets;
import com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util.CharacterSkin;
import com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util.Constants;
import com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util.GamePreferences;

public class MenuScreen extends AbstractGameScreen{
    private static final String TAG = MenuScreen.class.getName();

    private Stage stage;
    private Skin skinCanyonBunny;
    private Skin skinLibgdx;

    //Menu
    private Image imgBackground;
    private Image imgLogo;
    private Image imgInfo;
    private Image imgCoin;
    private Image imgBunny;
    private Button btnMenuPlay;
    private Button btnMenuOptions;

    //Opciones
    private Window winOptions;
    private TextButton btnWinOptSave;
    private TextButton btnwinOptCancel;
    private CheckBox chkSound;
    private Slider sldSound;
    private CheckBox chkMusic;
    private Slider sldMusic;
    private SelectBox selCharSkin;
    private Image imgCharSkin;
    private CheckBox chkShowFpsCounter;

    //Debug
    private final float DEBUG_REBUILD_INTERVAL = 5.0f;
    private boolean debugEnabled = false;
    private float debugRebuildStage;
    ShapeRenderer debugRenderer;


    public MenuScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);

    }

    private void rebuildStage () {


        skinCanyonBunny = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_CANYONBUNNY_UI),
            new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_UI));

        skinLibgdx = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.SKIN_LIBGDX_UI),
                new TextureAtlas(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_LIBGDX_UI));

        //Creacion de las layers
        Table layerBackground = buildBackgroundLayer();
        Table layerObjects = buildObjetsLayer();
        Table layerLogos = buildLogosLayer();
        Table layerControl = buildControlsLayer();
        Table layerOptionsWindow = buildOptionsWindowLayer();

        //Prepara el stage para la pantalla del menu
        stage.clear();
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        stage.addActor(stack);
        stack.setSize(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT);
        stack.add(layerBackground);
        stack.add(layerObjects);
        stack.add(layerLogos);
        stack.add(layerControl);
        stage.addActor(layerOptionsWindow);

    }

    private void loadSettings(){
        GamePreferences prefs = GamePreferences.instance;
        prefs.load();
        chkSound.setChecked(prefs.sound);
        sldSound.setValue(prefs.volSound);
        chkMusic.setChecked(prefs.music);;
        sldMusic.setValue(prefs.volMusic);
        //selCharSkin.getSelection().set(prefs.charSkin);
        selCharSkin.setSelected(prefs.charSkin);
        onCharSkinSelected(prefs.charSkin);
        chkShowFpsCounter.setChecked(prefs.showFpsCounter);

    }

    private void saveSettings(){
        GamePreferences prefs = GamePreferences.instance;
        prefs.sound = chkSound.isChecked();
        prefs.volSound = sldSound.getValue();
        prefs.music = chkMusic.isChecked();
        prefs.volMusic = sldMusic.getValue();
        prefs.charSkin = selCharSkin.getSelectedIndex();
        prefs.showFpsCounter = chkShowFpsCounter.isChecked();
        prefs.save();
    }

    private void onCharSkinSelected(int index) {
        CharacterSkin skin = CharacterSkin.values()[index];
        imgCharSkin.setColor(skin.getColor());

    }

    private void onSaveClicked(){
        saveSettings();
        onCancelClicked();
    }

    private void onCancelClicked() {
        btnMenuPlay.setVisible(true);
        btnMenuOptions.setVisible(true);
        winOptions.setVisible(false);
    }

    private Table buildOptWinAudioSettings(){
        Table tbl = new Table();
        //Titulo:Audio
        tbl.pad(10,10,0,10);
        tbl.add(new Label("Audio", skinLibgdx, "default-font", Color.ORANGE)).colspan(3);
        tbl.row();
        tbl.columnDefaults(0).padRight(10);
        tbl.columnDefaults(1).padRight(10);
        //CheckBox: Titulo Sound, sonido volumen
        chkSound = new CheckBox("", skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(chkSound);
        tbl.add(new Label("Sonido",skinLibgdx));
        sldSound = new Slider(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, false, skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(sldSound);
        tbl.row();
        //CheckBox:Titulo Musica, sonido musica
        chkMusic = new CheckBox("", skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(chkMusic);
        tbl.add(new Label("Musica", skinLibgdx));
        sldMusic = new Slider(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, false, skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(sldMusic);
        tbl.row();
        return tbl;
    }

    private Table buildOptWinSkinSelection(){//* Checkear
        Table tbl = new Table();
        //Titulo: Skin del Personaje
        tbl.pad(10, 10, 0, 10);
        tbl.add(new Label("Skin del Personaje", skinLibgdx, "default-font",
                Color.ORANGE)).colspan(2);
        tbl.row();
        //Selector de skin
        selCharSkin = new SelectBox(CharacterSkin.values(), skinLibgdx); 
        selCharSkin.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
                onCharSkinSelected(((SelectBox)actor).getSelectedIndex());
            }
        });
        tbl.add(selCharSkin).width(120).padRight(20);
        //Muestra del skin
        imgCharSkin = new Image(Assets.instance.bunny.head);
        tbl.add(imgCharSkin).width(50).height(50);
        return tbl;
    }

    private Table buildOptWinDebug(){

        Table tbl = new Table();
        //Titulo: "Debug"
        tbl.pad(10,10,0,10);
        tbl.add(new Label("Debug", skinLibgdx, "default-font", Color.RED)).colspan(3);
        tbl.row();
        tbl.columnDefaults(0).padRight(10);
        tbl.columnDefaults(1).padRight(10);
        //CheckBox: Mostrar FPS
        chkShowFpsCounter = new CheckBox("", skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(new Label("Mostrar FPS", skinLibgdx));
        tbl.add(chkShowFpsCounter);
        tbl.row();
        return tbl;
    }

    private Table buildOptWinButtons(){
        Table tbl = new Table();
        //Separador
        Label lbl = null;
        lbl = new Label("", skinLibgdx);
        lbl.setColor(0.75f,0.75f,0.75f,1);
        lbl.setStyle(new LabelStyle(lbl.getStyle()));
        lbl.getStyle().background = skinLibgdx.newDrawable("white");
        tbl.add(lbl).colspan(2).height(1).width(220).pad(0,0,0,1);
        tbl.row();
        lbl = new Label("", skinLibgdx);
        lbl.setColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1);
        lbl.setStyle(new LabelStyle(lbl.getStyle()));
        lbl.getStyle().background = skinLibgdx.newDrawable("white");
        tbl.add(lbl).colspan(2).height(1).width(220).pad(0,1,5,0);
        tbl.row();
        //Boton Salvar
        btnWinOptSave = new TextButton("Guardar", skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(btnWinOptSave).padRight(30);
        btnWinOptSave.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
                onSaveClicked();
            }
        });
        //Boton Cancelar
        btnwinOptCancel = new TextButton("Cancelar", skinLibgdx);
        tbl.add(btnwinOptCancel);
        btnwinOptCancel.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
                onCancelClicked();
            }
        });
        return tbl;
    }

    private Table buildOptionsWindowLayer() {
        winOptions = new Window("Opciones", skinLibgdx);
        //Audio Settings
        winOptions.add(buildOptWinAudioSettings()).row();
        //Personaje Settings
        winOptions.add(buildOptWinSkinSelection()).row();
        //Debug
        winOptions.add(buildOptWinDebug()).row();
        //Separador y botones
        winOptions.add(buildOptWinButtons()).pad(10, 0, 10, 0);

        //Ventana opciones un poco transparente
        winOptions.setColor(1,1,1,0.8f);
        //Ocultar la ventana por default
        winOptions.setVisible(false);
        if(debugEnabled)winOptions.debug();
        //Permitir a tablelayout recalcular el tamaño y posicion de los widgets
        winOptions.pack();
        //Mueve la ventana opciones para la parte derecha abajo
        winOptions.setPosition(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH - winOptions.getWidth() - 50,
                50);
        return winOptions;
    }

    private Table buildControlsLayer() {
        Table layer = new Table();
        layer.right().bottom();
        //Boton de Jugar
        btnMenuPlay = new Button(skinCanyonBunny, "play");
        layer.add(btnMenuPlay);
        btnMenuPlay.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
                onPlayClicked();
            }
        });
        layer.row();
        //Boton de Opciones
        btnMenuOptions = new Button(skinCanyonBunny, "options");
        layer.add(btnMenuOptions);
        btnMenuOptions.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                onOptionsClicked();

            }
        });
        if (debugEnabled)layer.debug();
        return layer;
    }

    private Table buildLogosLayer() {
        Table layer = new Table();
        layer.left().top();
        //Logo del juego
        imgLogo = new Image(skinCanyonBunny, "logo");
        layer.add(imgLogo);
        layer.row().expandY();
        //Info Logo
        imgInfo = new Image (skinCanyonBunny, "info");
        layer.add(imgInfo).bottom();
        if(debugEnabled) layer.debug();
        return layer;
    }

    private Table buildObjetsLayer() {
        Table layer = new Table();
        //Monedas
        imgCoin = new Image(skinCanyonBunny, "coins");
        layer.add(imgCoin);
        imgCoin.setPosition(135,80);
        //Conejo
        imgBunny = new Image(skinCanyonBunny, "bunny");
        layer.add(imgBunny);
        imgBunny.setPosition(355, 40);
        return layer;
    }

    private Table buildBackgroundLayer() {
        Table layer = new Table();
        //Background
        imgBackground = new Image(skinCanyonBunny, "background");
        layer.add(imgBackground);
        return layer;
    }

    private void onPlayClicked() {
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));

    }

    private void onOptionsClicked() {
        loadSettings();
        btnMenuPlay.setVisible(false);
        btnMenuOptions.setVisible(false);
        winOptions.setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        if (debugEnabled){
            debugRebuildStage -= deltaTime;
            if (debugRebuildStage <= 0){
                debugRebuildStage = DEBUG_REBUILD_INTERVAL;
                rebuildStage();
            }
        }
        stage.act(deltaTime);
        stage.draw();

    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(Math.round(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH), 
                Math.round(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT));


    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        rebuildStage();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        stage.dispose();
        skinCanyonBunny.dispose();
        skinLibgdx.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

GamePreferences.java

```
package com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;

public class GamePreferences {
    public static final String TAG = GamePreferences.class.getName();

    public static final GamePreferences instance = new GamePreferences();
    public boolean sound;
    public boolean music;
    public float volSound;
    public float volMusic;
    public int charSkin;
    public boolean showFpsCounter;

    private Preferences prefs;

    //singleton
    private GamePreferences (){
        prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES);
    }

    public void load (){
        sound = prefs.getBoolean("sound", true);
        music = prefs.getBoolean("music", true);
        volSound = MathUtils.clamp(prefs.getFloat("volSound", 0.5f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
        volMusic = MathUtils.clamp(prefs.getFloat("volMusic", 0.5f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
        charSkin = MathUtils.clamp(prefs.getInteger("charSkin", 0), 0, 2);
        showFpsCounter = prefs.getBoolean("showFpsCounter",  false);
    }

    public void save (){
        prefs.putBoolean("sound", sound);
        prefs.putBoolean("music", music);
        prefs.putFloat("volSound", volSound);
        prefs.putFloat("volMusic", volMusic);
        prefs.putInteger("charSkin", charSkin);
        prefs.putBoolean("showFpsCounter", showFpsCounter);
        prefs.flush();
    }
```

CharacterSkin.java

```
package com.packtub.libgdx.canyonbunny.util;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;

public enum CharacterSkin {
    WHITE("WHITE", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
    GRAY("Gray", 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f),
    BROWN("Brown", 0.7f, 0.5f, 0.3f);

    private String name;
    private Color color = new Color();

    private CharacterSkin(String name, float r, float g, float b){
        this.name = name;
        color.set(r, g, b, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry maybe I understand something wrong. This guy had the same problem as me: [link](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15002&p=65096)

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I misread the code.

Comment: I have look, but no, you never subclass Select Box, you just import the one you mention and work with it. Is there some way i can fix it?

Comment: Maybe change the code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CharacterSkin now uses generics for the item type. So you must specify the item type when you declare the reference and when you instantiate it. And you must use the `setItems()` method since the constructor no longer takes the list of items.

```
private SelectBox<CharacterSkin> selCharSkin;
```

and

```
selCharSkin = new SelectBox<CharacterSkin>(skinLibgdx);
selCharSkin.setItems(CharacterSkin.values());
```